# Is forward chaining space friendlier compared to backward chaining?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In the context of rule-based systems, is forward chaining more efficient than backward chaining?

I know that forward chaining is used when we know some facts and from there we want to conclude some new facts. For backward chaining we use it when we want to assert a particular hypothesis. Is forward chaining faster or more efficient in terms of space compared to backward chaining?

Comment: Can you clarify what the context is, i.e. what do you mean by forward and backward checking here? I know what forward checking is in CSP solving, but I'm not sure what you mean with backward checking (do you simply mean backtracking?)

Comment: @Juho sorry made a terrible error edited it now.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the edit! I tried to make it just a tiny bit better.

Comment: I think I remember reading the opposite in the [PowerLoom](http://www.isi.edu/isd/LOOM/PowerLoom/) documentation, but I can't find exactly where I've seen it.